# Azure machine learning studio get access to the file in upload zip file

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

I am trying to execute Python script from Azure machine learning studio. I had a script bundle(zip file) connect to the Python script as input. There are python files, txt files and other type of files in this zip file. My question is how do I get the file path from this zip file. For example, if I have language model in this  zip file, named lm.pcl, what's the file path of this language model? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're available under the `./Script Bundle` directory. For example, if you were to load a pickled model from the zip file, you'd write something along these lines:

```
import pandas as pd
import pickle

def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):

    model = pickle.load(open("./Script Bundle/model.pkl", "rb"))
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad. Problem is that I added an extra level of directory, which is my zip file name.